# a-frame ng-repeat don't display boxes if wrapped into a-entity

Tags: angularjs, aframe

Have a look [here](http://codepen.io/Disorrder/pen/vxBxYG): some boxes are wrapped into `a-entity`. If you unwrap them, boxes will appear. Looks like a bug.

But! If you see this codepen: codepen.io/Disorrder/pen/MpgJMB *(more than 2 links permitted for me now, sorry)*
You can see, I've wrapped some objects from "Hello World" a-frame scene into `a-entity` without angular, and this works good! I think, it's not problem of Angular, because all a-boxes' DOM rendered good, and you can also [inspect scene](https://gyazo.com/89d48ace7002f3a4f9648a8af502e478) and see all a-boxes. So may be that meshes just didn't added to a-entity's THREE.Group? That's weird :(

**UPD:** If I add `ng-if="true"`, it works as expected! But still weird